# Spotify with nextAuth does not return the log in page and returned 404

Tags: spotify, next-auth, next.js13

**I'm working on next Auth with spotify,** *suppose to direct me to the login of spotify but it's returned 404*

**[...nextauth].js**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import SpotifyProvider from "next-auth/providers/spotify"
import fetch from "node-fetch"
import { URLSearchParams } from "url"

const scopes = [
    "user-read-email",
    "playlist-read-private",
    "playlist-read-collaborative",
    "user-read-currently-playing",
    "user-modify-playback-state"
].join(",")

const params = {
    scope: scopes
}

const LOGIN_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' + new URLSearchParams(params).toString();

async function refreshAccessToken(token) {
    // refreshing an access token
    const params = new URLSearchParams()
    params.append("grant_type", "refresh_token")
    params.append("refresh_token", token.refreshToken)
    const response = await fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic' + (new Buffer.from(process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID + ':' + process.env.SPOTIFY_SECRET).toString('base64'))
        },
        body: params
    })
    const data = await response.json()
    return {
        accessToken: data.access_token,
        refreshToken: data.refresh_token ?? token.refreshToken,
        accessTokenExpires: Date.now() +  data.expires_in * 1000
    }
}

export const authOptions ={
    providers: [
        SpotifyProvider({
            clientId: process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.SPOTIFY_SECRET,
            authorization: LOGIN_URL,
        }),
    ],
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    pages: {
        signIn: "/login"
    },
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, account }) {
            //persist the Oauth access_token to the token right after signin
            if (account) {
                token.accessToken = account.access_token
                token.refreshToken = account.refresh_token
                token.accessTokenExpires = account.expires_at
                return token
            }

            //access token has not expired
            if (Date.now() < token.accessTokenExpires * 1000) {
                return token
            }

            //access token has expired
            return refreshAccessToken(token)
        },
        async session({ session, token, user }) {
            // send properties to the client, like access token
            session.accessToken = token.accessToken
            return session
        }
    }
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

*This is my nextauth.js*

*I have route my _app.js with SessionProvider*
**_app.js**

```
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"

export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

**providers.js**

```
"use client";

import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

export default function Providers({ children }) {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
}
```

**layout.js**

```
import Providers from './providers'

export const metadata = {
  title: 'ShinxDB',
  description: 'Generated by Shinx app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
          <Providers >
          {children}
          </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

**login/page.jsx**

```
"use client"
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react' 

export default function Login() {
  return (
    <div className='flex items-center justify-center'>
        <button onClick={() => signIn('spotify', { callbackUrl: "/"})}>Login with 
      spotify</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

*I route both the layout.js and _app.js with provider because I'm using the nextjs13 with app directory *